# ObjectBox Not downloading with Pod install and also on their Github Page

Tags: database, flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox, greenrobot-objectbox

An attempt to download the Zip "ObjectBox-xcframework-1.9.1.zip" from their Github page does not download And also doing "pod install --verbose" didn't download it.

Turning on and off my Mifi, Tried it from my mobile device but same thing

Comment: I can download the file from https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-swift/releases/tag/v1.9.1. This sound like a network or internet provider issue to me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Flutter Tag I suppose you want to add the package objectbox to a Flutter project.

You can add packages using the flutter pub add  key word.

In your case it would be `flutter pub add objectbox`.